# How to make html generated by `nuxt generate` fully static?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this very simple vue page located at `pageas/index.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>hello world</div>
</template>
```

After running `nuxt generate`, the generated html file `dist/index.html` doesn't have any "hello world" in it.

That means the generate site isn't fully static. It still requires a browser to run js to render the final html, and search engines might not be able to see html in vue pages.

I wonder is there anyway to make nuxt fully generated html files at least when the vue pages are static(e.g., don't have `asyncData` or `fetch` specified)?

Comment: This is not possible with nuxt without using SSR. You can take a look at gridsome as alternative: https://gridsome.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before running the generate command first set the application config to `universal` (SSR) mode.

In nuxt.config.js :

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal'
}
```

Then run : 
`npm run generate`